# Vue I18n doesn't work on pure javascript files

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, localization, mixins

I implemented https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/ i18n localization in my project. And it works very well on vue components/pages. But it doesn't work on pure javascript classes and mixins. Is there a way to handle it?

In **example.vue** component:

```
<template>
<p>{{ $t("message.hello") }}</p>
...
</template>
<script>
data:(){
...
},
methods:...
i18n: require('path of localization messages.')
</script>
```

But it is not work on **example.js(pure javascript)** or **example.mjs(mixins)** files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer from here: https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/287

You can import VueI18n instance.

e.g. app generated with vue-cli:

src/i18n.js:

```
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default new VueI18n({
  // ...
})
```

src/foo.js:

```
import i18n from './i18n'

console.log(i18n.t('foo.bar')
```